# Angular 5 BS4 how to make required vertical button group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, radio-button, angular5, required

I've so far tried a couple options with the 2nd one at least triggering validation but unable to display required msg due to hidden inputs.

1st try:-

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-block" data-toggle="buttons" required>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default border-primary" 
    [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': SUR.VAAD == 1}"
    (click)="SUR.VAAD = 1">
        Text1
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default border-primary" 
    [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': SUR.VAAD == 2}"
    (click)="SUR.VAAD = 2">
        Text2
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default border-primary" 
    [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': SUR.VAAD == 3}"
    (click)="SUR.VAAD = 3">
        Text3
    </button>
</div>
```

2nd try:-

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical" data-toggle="buttons" required>
    <div *ngFor="let option of VAADOptions">
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block border-primary" style="width:100%" (click)="SUR.VAAD = option.value"
        [ngClass]="{'btn-primary': SUR.VAAD == option.value}">
        <input type="radio" name="VAAD" [(ngModel)]="SUR.VAAD" [value]="option.value" hidden required>
        <div [innerHTML]="option.display"></div>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course with the 2nd try it doesn't render as a group but does work correctly as radiobuttons.

That and the 2nd option will trigger validation but won't display a msg as it can't focus on hidden inputs.

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: well I can fix the 2nd try focus issue by using the tips on this page https://tiffanybbrown.com/2015/11/an-invalid-form-control-is-not-focusable/index.html althought I'd prefer being able to use actual buttons instead of labels and inputs.

Comment: and ofc another drawback to my 2nd approach being that I can't disable any of the buttons making it a botch job. I solved this by using [ngClass] and applying a class to make it look disabled alongside changing the click event from directly setting the value to instead call a function that would change the value if it detects the form isn't disabled.